# Which part of speech do these words belong to?

Tags: category

This probably isn't a complete list of these types of words, but I am wanting to know what category these words go into:

- quality
- attribute
- property

Comment: It certainly isn't complete. They're _abstract nouns_, and there are thousands more. These particular abstract nouns describe abstractions (i.e, ideas, not things) used by philosophers or semanticists or logicians or mathematicians or programmers to label various parts -- especially **categories** of parts -- of the abstractions they create.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken they're all 3-sylable words.

Comment: You need to explain what kind of categorisation system you want. There's so many ways you could categorise them: phonology, type of speech, etymology...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they're all used the same way, then they're **abstract nouns**. But some can be used in other ways, and hence belong to a different part of speech.

**quality** - abstract noun (*the quality of something* OR *The person's qualities*) OR adjective (*a quality piece of writing*)

**attribute** - abstract noun (*The person's positive attributes*)

**property** - concrete noun (*I have lots of property*) OR abstract noun (*The mineral's properties*)

Comment: Also _attribute_ – verb (_His symptoms were attributed to stress_).